# React routing not working in react boilerplate

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to route but it is not working it shows a blank page
here is the code
when I hit localhost:3000/home it is not showing anything

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";


const Home = () =>{
  return(
      <div>
        <p>Home</p>
      </div>
  );
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/home' Component={Home}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: And also it doesn't have any error in console

Comment: Try to render simple home path '/' first. Also change name home to something else and see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**component** prop in `<Route />` is case-sensitive, make it lower case

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
```